# Codeigniter session to convert to use native sessions php

Tags: codeigniter, session, native

I am using codeigniter to develop php website for a month. But recently I find out that session seems to have problems. sometimes it loss and sometimes it cannot kill.

Is it a issue? As it is very important if session has problems.
After google in the website, it can change to use native session. How to change it? Can it really solve the issues?

Comment: Explain more about your question !!

Comment: Would proxy make my computer browser of my website to have session variables problems??